# Create custom YUM repository for a server with no internet connection

Tags: yum, repository, metadata

I have an OracleLinux 8.8 server which can not access the Internet, hence no access for public repos. Also there is quite small amount of storage available, so I can not put fully synced repos there. I am trying to find a way to get just the right install/update packages for this server and create a custom repo from them.

I was able to get the packages - I think at least. This far I got until now:

- created a current package list on the target server (rpm -qa > packagelist.txt) - also added some extra packages to be installed
- I set up a VirtualBox VM with similar version
- in the VM, set up the same repos the target server would want to reach
- used `yumdownloader --resolve ...` to get all the packages available
- run `createrepo` on the downloaded files
- copied the new repo to the target server and configured to be used by yum

Now the problem is that `yum` is complaining abot the lack of package groups metadata. When I create a full copy of an online repo using `reposync --download-metadata ...` then I have the package group info. But how to prepare it for my custom repository?

**EDIT:** I managed to install my most needed packages via an alternative method: setting up socks5 proxy using SSH tunnels. This can work on some occasions - not for production servers.

So I would need to be able to get information about all needed packages and then download them separately with all of theyr relevant metadata structures (sreams, groups, etc) and then copy this minimal amount of install packages to the target server.

On AIX servers there is a tool, called **compare_report** which is able to get a list of all installed packages - the AIX equivalent of **rpm -qa** - form two servers and tell exactly what to install on one of them to match exactly the other.

Comment: You should be able to use `rpm -qa` on your OracleLinux, as YUM is just a "frontend" for `rpm`.

Comment: Yes, i can. Also I did run **rpm -qa** trying to create an input list to make a repository. My problem is that  I can not install "stream" packages, like Python, without the group/stream metadata info. Is there a way to build metadata containing this info as well?

Well, I know that I can use **reposync --download-metadata ...** to get a full repo. The problem is, there is not enough space to copy full repos to the protected server. That's why I would like to make a repo that contains only packages that are needed, bundled with all relevant metadata.

Comment: If you have direct access to the system, I would just add another disk to the system. 64GiB should be enough.

Comment: Yes, but az this moment this is not an option. Maybe an USB drive could be attached, but that is really cumbersome. I hope there might be a solution, not just a workaround.

Comment: In my opinion, a server which has not even 64GiB free disk space is the problem. I mean, what costs a GiB? 18TiB Seagate Exos enterprise HDD costs just 275€, this is just 1€ for 64GiB. So I think, this would be the cheaper and faster solution than to waste any more workhours onto it.

Comment: That's almost right. Except that this is a virtualized environement with very limited resources - mostly not beacause the cost. Anyhow, the correct way to serve a bunch of small prod servers would be to build a dedicated repo server with enough resources. I was hoping for a solution without that.